# Retain parent state in AngularUI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an application with AngularJS which has a phonebook. The state `page.phonebook` contains a list with users and companies and a form with filters. The data is loaded via ngResource from the backend. If I click on a user, I'm getting to the users detail page. When I now do a browser back (backspace), I'm getting back to the phonebook list, but with a new `$scope`. That means that I lost the old state with all my filters, data, etc.

I guess the problem is that I load the state `page.phonebook.user` in the `page` view, which replaces the `page.phonebook` state.

But is it somehow possible to retain the old state? This includes the scroll position, the filter values and the data from the server.

This is my state configuration:

```
$stateProvider
.state('page', {
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'PageController',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/page.html',
})
.state('page.phonebook', {
    url: "^/phonebook",
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/page.phonebook.html',
    controller: 'PhonebookController'
})
.state('page.phonebook.user', {
    url: "^/user/:userId",
    views: {
        '@page': {
            controller: 'UserController',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/page.user.html'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `ngRouteProvider` instead of `stateProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well maintain the state. You need to persist the filters, and scrolling position as part of your stateparams or a service. Once you are navigating between the pages you can retrieve that back.

Comment: I was hoping that there's an even easier solution for this. I'll create a service then. Thanks for your help.